# Is there a way to determine the setting of the Ring/Silent switch on the iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am trying to figure out from my code whether the Ring/Silent switch is on ring or silent. Is there a way to determine this from my program.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some more searching and found the same question here [How to detect iphone is on silent mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833304).

For completeness, here is the answer from Neil that worked for me?

```
CFStringRef state = nil;
UInt32 propertySize = sizeof(CFStringRef);
AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
OSStatus status = AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute, &propertySize, &state);

if (status == kAudioSessionNoError) { 
    return (CFStringGetLength(state) == 0);   // YES = silent
}
return NO;
```

It should be noted that this will not work if headphones are connected. You will always get "HeadPhone". This was also reported by coob.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.

You can configure how your audio session is affected by the switch, but you cannot tell whether it's on or off.