# How to check if sound off on iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, audio

can I programmatically check if sound off in iPhone by this button http://osxdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/iphone-mute-camera-sound.jpg. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833304/how-to-detect-iphone-is-on-silent-mode/5005904#5005904

Comment: it doesn't work for me (ios 7 beta 6) :(

Comment: iOS7 is still under NDA, we can't talk about it here, ask [Apple developers forums](https://developer.apple.com/devforums/)