# AVPlayer plays sound even if silent button was already off before playing

Tags: ios, swift

When I move the silent button on or off, it behaves correctly. My issue is at the start, if the switch is off (silent mode on) the video play sounds, but I don't want this. I already tried with Ambient and AmbientSolo categories, maybe this is the intended behavior, I don't know.

Comment: I think it is the intended behaviour. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34105022/ios-9-how-to-detect-silent-mode