# Xamarin.iOS -> Is there an event to listen when user switch from ring/silent mode on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I would like to know when user switch from silent/ring. Is there an event I can listen in the ViewController to detected when this silent/ring property changed?

Thank you,

Comment: Maybe use this post for tips: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833304/how-to-detect-iphone-is-on-silent-mode

Answer (score 1):

There is no public API that you can listen when this silent button get change. Apple in response to some request has answered like this

> We never have provided a method for detecting hardware mute switch and
>   don't intend to do so.