# How to detect if the iphone is on mute

Tags: iphone, mute

Im wondering if I can test whether the iPhone is set on mute. How can I do this? I searched for it a while but I didn't find a good solution!

Thanks
Markus

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programatically sense the iPhone mute switch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287543/how-to-programatically-sense-the-iphone-mute-switch)

Comment: Same question : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287543/how-to-programatically-sense-the-iphone-mute-switch

Comment: but this does not work for me...

Answer (score 2):

This thread has the answer to your question:
[How to programmatically sense the iPhone mute switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287543/how-to-programatically-sense-the-iphone-mute-switch)

Hope this helps