# Playing sound while the app is inactive/in background with respect to mute/ring-switch

Tags: iphone, audio, ios4

I want to play sound while my app is in the background and respect the mute-ring-switch.

I managed to play sound while my app is not in the foreground. I use basically the following code to play my sound:

```
sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileUrl error:nil];
sound.numberOfLoops = -1;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
/* ... */
[sound playAtTime:0];
```

AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback causes my application to ignore the silent/ring-switch and play sound in background.

Since I want to have the last behavior without the first, I searched for a solution to query the state of the silent/rind-switch. I tried different approaches but this seemed to work for most of the users:

```
 -(BOOL)silenced {
 #if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
     // return NO in simulator. Code causes crashes for some reason.
     return NO;
 #endif

CFStringRef state;
UInt32 propertySize = sizeof(CFStringRef);
AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute, &propertySize, &state);
if(CFStringGetLength(state) > 0)
        return NO;
else
        return YES;

}
```

I found it here:
[How to programmatically sense the iPhone mute switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287543/how-to-programatically-sense-the-iphone-mute-switch)

This code isn't working for me. Despite the phone is muted "state" is not empty.

Does anyone have an idea, why this isn't working for me? I am developing and testing for iOS 4.3.

Thx.

**Edit** I used CFShow to show the content of the kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute and it is "Speaker" everytime, nontheless I changed the state of the mute/ring switch.