# iOS5 openAL mute switch and volume controls

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, openal

I am currently using `openAL` for audio playback in my app and having problems with the audio responding to the mute switch and audio volume controls in iOS 5.

I have set up an audio session category for ambient sound and it operates correctly `pre-iOS 5`.

Has anyone had any similar problems?

Comment: Hi yes.  I'm having this issue too. I've seen some people talk about adding an observer to the AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification.  But there have been comments that this can fail your submission to Apple.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I ended up fixing my problem. It was related to MPMoviePlayerController messing around with openAL (still have no idea what though). I simply reactivated the openAL context after a movie and everything worked ok

Comment: Please mark this question as solved in that case

Comment: For everyone directed here from google, here is a similar SO with an good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340221/ios-openal-and-silent-switch

Answer (score 0):

If you watch what happens when you click that button, you can see that it initially makes a request to a redirect script on www.angrybirds.com:

http://www.angrybirds.com/redirect.php?device=iphone&product=angrybirds&type=purchasegift

From there you are redirected to a secure url of the form:

https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/giftSongsWizard?gift=1&salableAdamId=343200656&productType=C&pricingParameter=STDQ

343200656 is the AppleID for Angry Birds.

Further you can reffer below link:
["Gift App" from inside the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197035/gift-app-from-inside-the-app)