# Is there a way to check the mute status?

Tags: ios, xcode, mute

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to programatically sense the iPhone mute switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287543/how-to-programatically-sense-the-iphone-mute-switch)

I want my app to check wether the mute switch is toggled on or off! But there is one problem... Is there a function for it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[How to programmatically sense the iPhone mute switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287543/how-to-programatically-sense-the-iphone-mute-switch)

I do believe this is what you are looking for.

Posting the code here:

```
// "Ambient" makes it respect the mute switch
// Must call this once to init session
if (!gAudioSessionInited)
{
    AudioSessionInterruptionListener    inInterruptionListener = NULL;
    OSStatus    error;
    if ((error = AudioSessionInitialize (NULL, NULL, inInterruptionListener, NULL)))
    {
        NSLog(@"*** Error *** error in AudioSessionInitialize: %d.", error);
    }
    else
    {
        gAudioSessionInited = YES;
    }
}

SInt32  ambient = kAudioSessionCategory_AmbientSound;
if (AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof (ambient), &ambient))
{
        NSLog(@"*** Error *** could not set Session property to ambient.");
}
```