# Mute is overridden when using the mic for recording

Tags: iphone, ios, microphone, recording, mute

My initial issue was as described in the title there. When I was recording from the mic, sound effects were playing at the same time even if the device was in mute mode (i.e., had the mute button physically switched on).

I since found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287543/how-to-programmatically-sense-the-iphone-mute-switch), which totally worked. the mute button now works correctly, and no sounds are played in the app while the mic is recording...

Unfortunately, the mic has now stopped recording!

It seems like I can have one or the other, but not both. Can anyone confirm if I can have the device on mute and record from the mic at the same time? And if so, how?

Thank you so much in advance,

Stew

UPDATE : I'm fairly certain that this isn't possible, and I'm basing this on the fact that the mute switch also doesn't work in Garage Band (Another app which requires simultanious playback and recording).

To try it yourself, simply load up Garage Band, play some music, and then note that the mute switch doesn't work.

I'm leaving this open in case anyone does come up with a solution, but I won't be offended if it's closed or deleted.