# How to set the volume mute in movie player in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am creating an app regarding movie player. In movie player I played videos. It worked fine but I want to mute the volume through coding. I want to set one button for volume mute. When I click the button it performs actions for mute. How can I proceed for this?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287543/how-to-programmatically-sense-the-iphone-mute-switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there is no such mute option available. But you can set volume through codebase. Check this Apple documentation, it might be helpful to you:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html