# How to detect iPhone Silent Button Status in iOS6

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6, silent, mute

I have been using following code to detect the iPhone silent button status but it sometimes worked but usually dont work. I have searched alot but wont be able to figure out the solution yet.

-(void)playWordSoundWithFile:(NSString*)filePath {

```
audioPlayer = nil;



if (filePath) {

    NSArray *list = [filePath componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    if (list && [list isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] && [list count] > 1) {

        //audioPlayer = [self audioPlayerWithFile:[list objectAtIndex:0] andExtension:@"mp3"];//[list objectAtIndex:1]
        NSString *soundFileIs=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",[list objectAtIndex:0],[list objectAtIndex:1]];
        NSString *paths = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
        NSString *audioFile = [paths stringByAppendingPathComponent:soundFileIs];
        NSData *cdata =[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:audioFile];

        NSLog(@"Sound file %@",soundFileIs);

        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:cdata error:nil];
        audioPlayer.delegate = self;

    }
}

if (audioPlayer) {

    [audioPlayer setVolume:1.0];
    playerId = 16;
    [audioPlayer play];

}
```

}

Comment: What do u want to achieve ?

Comment: actually the issue is when i play a sound and then switch iPhone to mute the sound continues to play it wont go mute thats why ma trying to do so.

Comment: i have posted the code which m using to play sound.

Answer (score 0):

Here just return your BOOL value.

```
-(BOOL)silenced {
     #if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
         // return NO in simulator. Code causes crashes for some reason.
         return NO;
     #endif

    CFStringRef state;
    UInt32 propertySize = sizeof(CFStringRef);
    AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute, &propertySize, &state);
    if(CFStringGetLength(state) > 0)
            return NO;
    else
            return YES;

    }
```

Please also check [How to programmatically sense the iPhone mute switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287543/how-to-programmatically-sense-the-iphone-mute-switch) All the methods to mute are provided here. Hope this helps.

Comment: it always returns No.