# Get Notification when iPhone silent On or Off in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

My application is running mode. and i want to check in running mode.Means when user set on/off ,i want to get any notification to handle it.

My requirement is when user set silent mode of iPhone Lable color should be change.

So how I get listener when user set mode on/off of silent switch?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically sense the iPhone mute switch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287543/how-to-programmatically-sense-the-iphone-mute-switch)

Answer (score 1):

There is no public API that you can listen when this silent button get change.
Apple in response to some request has answered like this

> We never have provided a method for detecting hardware mute switch and
>   don't intend to do so.