# How to check if mobile is in silent ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, audio, avaudioplayer

I am working on developing a swift app. How can I check whether a mobile is in silent mode? Is there any method to find that the phone is now silent or its volume is high? Please help me.

I searched but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: You should explain why you need to know this. That will allow people to possibly offer an appropriate solution.

Comment: @HangarRash because I add it in webView app to call via javascript function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287543/how-to-programmatically-sense-the-iphone-mute-switch

Comment: @shim its not working because its objective-c and the old is also old I try it many times.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Public API for check that.

There is Mute Lib that works with work around.

https://github.com/akramhussein/Mute

Comment: I just want to deduct weather the phone is silent or not.